# How to use Signal after a Save is called

Tags: django

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Connector(models.Model):
    connector_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False,unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)

class ConnectorAud(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    ref_connector_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False,unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Connector)
def create_connector_audit_trail(sender, **kwargs):
    connector = ConnectorAud(
            ref_connector_id = kwargs.get('connector_id'),
            name        =   kwargs.get('name'),
            description =   kwargs.get('description',''),
    )
connector.save()
```

This causes Connector() to run twice when connector.save() is run

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add `dispatch_uid` with unique name to `@receiver` decorator to avoid duplicate signals (for example when you import file with signal several times, signal will be registered multiple times if unique `dispatch_uid` is not present).

You receiver is called each time when model is saved, if you want to create `ConnectorAud` only once when Connector is created for first time you should add `created` param to you receiver method like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Connector,
          dispatch_uid='create_connector_audit_trail')
def create_connector_audit_trail(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        ConnectorAud.objects.create(ref_connector_id=instance.pk,
                                    name=instance.name,
                                    description=instance.description)
```

With this, when you will edit and save `Connector`, `ConnectorAud` will not be created multiple times.

Comment: Changing kwargs to instance works in this case. Thanks!